# List all items from the S3 Bucket with API Gateway on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I'm using API Gateway to get my images on S3, but I'm only able to get an object that I already know the name of.

So I need a way to list all the items in the bucket so I can get the objects I want.

```
https://awsdomain/v1/s3/?key=name-bucket%2Fname-object
```